# Correct connection between python scripts - stdin, stdout

Tags: python

I want to send images (numpy.ndarray in string format) to another script. The second script does some stuff with image and wait for another image.

The first script has the following loop:

```
while True:
    out = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w')
    [here some code]
    img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', ndarray)[1].tostring()
    out.write(img)
```

The second :

```
while True:
    data = sys.stdin.read()
    [here some code]
```

usage:

> $ python script1.py | python script2.py

The first iteration is ok. Second script obtains image and do some stuff. Then there is the second iteration and the following error:

```
out.write(img)
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
close failed in file object destructor:
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Then the `data` var in the second script is empty. What is wrong in this code?
If i have : `out = os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w')` above the loop, in the second script the line : `data = sys.stdin.read()` is infinite.

Comment: Conventionally, one Python module passes data to another by `import`ing the second module and calling whatever methods should receive the data. There are valid reasons to not do this, but you should consider carefully whether your use case is one of them.

Comment: If you really want to do this, consider `pickle` module

Comment: How would you expect any iteration other than the first one to work ever? `read()` reads until end of file. EOF == end of file == file is closed == won't be anything further there later.

Comment: (And what do you expect the playing around with `fileno()` to do?)

Comment: If you want to go this way you should consider some kind of a protocol (sending the size first and only then the data), so that at the other end to know how much to read; or some kind of message guards, for example to know when one image ends and another begins. Or you could use some kind of _IPC_ protocol that your _OS_ supports (e.g. the _sockets_).

Comment: @cricket_007, what would `pickle` do here? Since what's being transferred are bytestrings, the only thing pickle would do is make them bigger -- it wouldn't solve the problem of being able to delimit when one stops and the next one begins without inhibiting streaming at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reading to EOF, send length as a separate field, and read only that many bytes.

On the writing side:

```
while True:
    # [here some code]
    img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', ndarray)[1].tostring()
    sys.stdout.write(str(len(img)) + '\n')
    sys.stdout.write(img)
```

On the reading side, personally, I'd suggest a generator:

```
def inputStream():
    while True:
        header_line = sys.stdin.readline()
        if header_line == '': # file was closed on the input side
            raise StopIteration()
        len = int(header_line.strip())
        img = sys.stdin.read(len)
        yield img

for image in inputStream():
    pass # do something with "image" here
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The Error

You're seeing those errors, because in the first script (reading image data) file descriptors are being created in the loop.

It works in the first iteration, but in the 2nd iteration of the loop the file object referenced by the variable `out` goes out of scope (being replaced by the new file object), and while the file object is being destructed, the underlying file descriptor gets closed.

So the new file object (2nd time variable `out` is populated) is not a valid file descriptor anymore.

#### The Design (can help to be the solution)

I assume the reason 2 separate scripts are being used (code is broken into 2 different modules) may be:

- code structure: then I suggest using well defined modules, and import the processor in the first one (the running app). So you won't need to pass information between separate processes and dealing with IO, can use use function calls and passing arguments.
- multiprocessing: If you need to use different scripts to be able to have multiple processes cooperating, then I suggest using standard library [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) which provides nice inter process communication mechanism, so you won't need to deal with file objects, descriptors, stdout/stdin, etc. I would use a multiprocessing `Queue`, the first script populates the queue (`put`), and 2nd script consumes (`get`)